# Selecting elements in one set that do not contain an attribute of the other

Tags: jquery

Not entirely sure how to phrase the title, but here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var items = editArea.children();
var previewedItems = previewArea.children();

var unPreviewedItems = items.filter(function () {
    // ??
});
```

I have an `editArea` and a `preview` area. The user appends divs to the editArea, each with an increasing ID and `data-scid` of `item1`, `item2`, etc. and when a button is clicked, those divs are cloned into the preview area. Each clone has its ID prefixed with `preview_`, with the `data-scid`s left unchanged. I want to get a list of elements that I haven't yet cloned, essentially something like `unPreviewedItems = items.not(previewedItems)`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map (e.g. an object with keys as the name) of all your previewed items using a key with the `preview_` removed from the name.

Then, iterate through all the unpreviewed items and make a new list of the ones that are not found in the previous map.

```
// create the already previewed map
var map = {};
previewArea.children().each(function() {
    var id = this.id.replace(/^preview_/, "");
    map[id] = true;
});

var unpreviewed = [];
// iterate through the whole list of items
editArea.children().each(function() {
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
        unpreviewed.push(this);
    }
});
```